# Emulation in selenium with node not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

**Problem** 
This code should open up mobile emulation in chrome but for some reason it is not working i am using Selenium with express. Chrome opens but not in emulation mode and no errors appear

```
 const express = require('express')
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const app = express()
const port = 5000
var capabilities = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
      mobileEmulation: {
          deviceName: 'Apple iPhone 6'
      }
  }
};
async function google() {
  var driver = await new webdriver
    .Builder()
    .withCapabilities(capabilities)
    .build();
  await driver.get('https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent')
  
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  google()
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var capabilities = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  goo:chromeOptions: {
      mobileEmulation: {
          deviceName: 'Apple iPhone 6'
      }
  }
};
```

you should use goo:chromeOptions  https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.31/notes.txt

you can also use chrome options as :

```
 let options = new chrome.Options().setMobileEmulation(
     {deviceName: 'Google Nexus 5'});

 let driver = chrome.Driver.createSession(options);
```

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Options.html